# Get max date for each from either of 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, aggregate

I have a table like below

```
AID  BID  CDate 
-----------------------------------------------------
1   2     2018-11-01 00:00:00.000
8   1     2018-11-08 00:00:00.000
1   3     2018-11-09 00:00:00.000
7   1     2018-11-15 00:00:00.000
6   1     2018-12-24 00:00:00.000
2   5     2018-11-02 00:00:00.000
2   7     2018-12-15 00:00:00.000
```

And I am trying to get a result set as follows

```
ID        MaxDate
-------------------
1         2018-12-24 00:00:00.000
2         2018-12-15 00:00:00.000
```

Each value in the id columns(AID,BID) should return the max of CDate .

ex: in the case of 1, its max CDate is 2018-12-24 00:00:00.000 (here 1 appears under BID)
in the case of 2 , max date is 2018-12-15 00:00:00.000 . (here 2 is under AID)

I tried the following.
1.

```
select 
  g.AID,g.BID,
  max(g.CDate) as 'LastDate'
from dbo.TT g
inner join 
   (select AID,BID,max(CDate) as maxdate
    from dbo.TT
    group by AID,BID)a
on (a.AID=g.AID or a.BID=g.BID)
and a.maxdate=g.CDate
group by g.AID,g.BID
```

and 2.

```
SELECT
    AID,
    CDate
FROM (
   SELECT
       *, 
       max_date = MAX(CDate) OVER (PARTITION BY [AID])
   FROM dbo.TT
) AS s
WHERE CDate= max_date
```

Please suggest a 3rd solution.

Comment: Why only 1 and 2 in the expected results?

Comment: Try to Join AID and BID in a query and return just the Distinct matched ID. So you have all valid ID.  Then return all rows which contains this number in AID or BID. So you get all valid rows. Split this valid rows in the format like you want to have. One row should be split with the AID as ID the other BID as ID. Select again all ID which are in the list of valid id. Then you can aggregate of top of that easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assemble the data in a table expression first, and the compute the max for each value is simple. For example:

```
select
  id, max(cdate)
from (
  select aid as id, cdate from t 
  union all 
  select bid, cdate from t
) x
group by id
```

Comment: I think you list all id and not which are on both. To avoid it you can make additional having statement which checks if the id exists in aid and bid. Something like Having EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.aid = id) and Exists (SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.bid = id); I don't tested it!

Comment: I may be wrong but it seems it's not necessary to check it's on both sides. The title says "either". I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: actually maybe you right. I was just confused that just line 1 and 2 appears!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to only care about values that are in both columns.  If this interpretation is correct, then:

```
select id, max(cdate)
from ((select aid as id, cdate, 1 as is_a, 0 as is_b
       from t
      ) union all
      (select bid as id, cdate, 1 as is_a, 0 as is_b
       from t
      ) 
     ) ab
group by id
having max(is_a) = 1 and max(is_b) = 1;
```

Comment: 7 is in both columns but not in the expected results.

Comment: @forpas: i just showed a sample of the result set.Thanks